# Search substring with Rails Solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, full-text-search

I use gem sunspot_solr for full-text searching but I need search substring, example: "teststring", I need searched this typing 'est', 'tr', 'ing'...

What I need do for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Add this code inside 
rails_dir/solr/conf/schema.xml

Under text/string field type. 

<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        .
        .
        .
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="20" side="front"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="20" side="back"/>
      </analyzer>
```